# Why is Django creating my TextField as a varchar in the PostgreSQL database?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, psycopg2

Django 1.7, Python 3.4.

In my models I have several TextFields defined.

When I go to load a JSON fixture (which was generated from an SQLite3 dump), it fails on the second object, which has 515 characters for one of its fields.

The error printed is

`psycopg2.DataError: value too long for type character varying(500)`

I created a new database (not just a table drop, a whole new db), modified my settings.py file, ran `manage.py syncdb` on the new database, created a user, and tried to load the data again, getting the same error.

Upon opening pgAdmin3, all columns, both CharField and TextField defined are listed as type `character var`.

So it seems TextField is being ignored and CharFields are being created instead.  The PostgreSQL documentation explicitly lists both text and character types, and defines text as being unlimited in length.  Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure the model hasn't changed and the field is still a TextField?>

Comment: Ugh, why do ORMs insist on setting arbitrary limits? Django should just use `text` or unconstrained `varchar`.

Comment: @CraigRinger I agree django and others should default to 95% general use case, but I do understand the need for keeping databases small and fast for the high-load applications.   Interestingly Postgres says there is no speed penalty for using Text over varchar, but all varchars are restricted, which seems odd.


Unless I'm doing something specifically with huge amounts of data I'll just be using TextField in all Django apps from here on out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the *exact* cause was, but it seems to be related to django's migration tool storing migrations, even on a new database.

What I did to get this behavior:

- Create django project, then apps, using CharField
- syncdb, run the project's dev server
- kill the devserver, modify fields to be TextField
- Create a new Postgres database, modify settings.py
- Run syncdb, attempt to load fixtures
- See the error in question, examine db instance

What fixed the problem:

- Create a new database, modify settings.py
- delete all migrations in apps/migrations folders
- after running syncdb, also run createmigrations and migrate

The last step generated a migration, even though there were none stored in the migrations folder, and there had been no changes to models or data since syncdb was run on the new database, which I found to be odd.

Somewhere in the last two steps this was fixed.  Future people stumbling upon this: sorry, I'm not going to keep creating django projects to test the behavior further, but perhaps with this information you can fix your own database problems.